# Как перевести HTTP запрос на python

Tags: python, http, авторизация, auth

```
    $ curl -s -X POST \
  -d '{"version": "5c7d5dc6dd8bf75c1acaa8565735e7986bc5b66206b55cca93cb72c9bf15ccaa", "input": {"text": "Alice"}}' \
  -H "Authorization: Token d140e447625802167cd0703dc0cd267c46e0de0aa" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions
```

Такой HTTP запрос. Его нужно перевести на питон, но у меня не получается(((

Попробовал такой способ, не работает, говорит, что я не авторизован. В чем ошибка?

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions'
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token d40e447625802167cd0703dc0cd267c46e0de0aa',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
data = {
    'version': '5c7d5dc6dd8bf75c1acaa8565735e7986bc5b66206b55cca93cb72c9bf15ccaa',
    'input': {
        'text': 'Alice'
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
print(response.json())
```

API Документация по которой пишу https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http#authentication

Comment: сам запрос составлен правильно. Теперь читаем ошибку Incorrect authentication token. Learn how to authenticate and get your API token here: https://replicate.com/docs/reference/http#authentication

что-то не так с токеном

Comment: Токен верный т.к он по этой ссылке мне его и дает

Comment: странно. Я даже через ChatGPT проверил. Код должен быть таким